# Ignore white spaces for comparison in unique constraints of Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, unique-constraint

How can I tell to Oracle DBMS to ignore white spaces while comparing varchar values for Unique Constraints.

It means that `NAME 1` is exists in a table column with Unique Key, inserting `NAME1`, causes constraint violation exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with a unique *constraint* but you can do this with a unique *index*:

```
create unique index ix_name 
   on the_table(regexp_replace(the_column, '\s+', ''));
```

If you want a case-insensitive index (where `name 1` and `NAME 1` are taken as the same value) you need to convert everything to lower or uppercase:

```
create unique index ix_name 
   on the_table(upper(regexp_replace(the_column, '\s+', '')));
```

Comment: is there any solution to set for all database unique indices? like nls_comp

Comment: @MohsenKashi: not, there is no such thing

Answer (score 0):

Unique index does what you want. If you really want a constraint, you can create a unique constraint on a virtual column:

```
SQL> create table t1(c1 varchar2(100));

Table created.

SQL> alter table t1 add c2 generated always as (cast (regexp_replace(c1, '\s+') as varchar2(100))) virtual;

Table altered.

SQL> alter table t1 add constraint c1_unique unique(c2);

Table altered.

SQL> insert into t1 (c1) values ('Name 1');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t1 (c1) values ('Name1');
insert into t1 (c1) values ('Name1')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (BP.C1_UNIQUE) violated

SQL> select constraint_name, constraint_type from user_constraints;

CONSTRAINT_NAME C
--------------- -
C1_UNIQUE       U
```

Then you can even disable the constraint, if you want that:

```
SQL> alter table t1 disable constraint c1_unique;

Table altered.

SQL> insert into t1 (c1) values ('Name1');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t1 (c1) values ('Name 1');

1 row created.
```

Note that, this drops the index.